# PHP - Insert Into Associative Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to populate a mysql associative (many to many) table via a form submit.  Basically, trying to use this page to associate a "Red Flag" to one-to-many "Products".

[Screenshot of input form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIS55.png)

**FORM**

```
<?php

require 'connect-db.php';

$sql = "SELECT ID, prod_name FROM catalog";
$result =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<p><strong>Add Red Flag:</strong></p>

<form action="addRedFlag.php" method="post" id="rfForm">
<p>Description:
<br/><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="rfDescription" form="rfForm"></textarea>
<p>Severity: <br/>
<input type="radio" name="severity" value="minor"/>Minor<br/>
<input type="radio" name="severity" value="moderate"/>Moderate<br/>
<input type="radio" name="severity" value="major"/>Major<p/>
<select name="prod_id">
    <option value="">Choose a product</option>
    <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>
    <?php $id = $row['ID']; ?>
    <?php $title = $row['prod_name']; ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $title; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
<p/><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></form><br>

<a href="captureRedFlag.php"> Reset Form </a><br>
<a href="displayRedFlag.php"> View Red Flag List</a><br>
<a href="../../index.html"> Home</a>

</body>

</html>
```

**PHP HANDLER**

```
<?php

// connect to the database
include("connect-db.php");

$value1 = $_POST['rfDescription'];
$value2 = $_POST['severity'];
$value3 = $_POST['prod_id'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO redFlag (description, severity) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2')";
$sql2 = "SELECT ID FROM redFlag WHERE (description = '$value1')"; 
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO prod_RF (cat_id, rf_id) VALUES ('$value3', '$value4')";

$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql2);

if ($result1) 
{
    if ($result2) 
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
        $value4 = $row['ID'];
//      echo $value4;
        $result3 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql3);
        if ($result3)
        {
            echo "success";
        }
        else {echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);}
    }
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

When executed, the code completes successfully BUT the value of rf_id in prod_RF table is always zero.  This is strange because when I uncomment the

```
echo $value4;
```

line, the expected value is printed to the screen.  For some reason, when I attempt to use that same value ($value4) as input to a SQL query ($sql3), something fails.

Thanks for any suggestions as I'm pretty new to all this.

Comment: just after `$value3 = $_POST['prod_id'];` define `$value4 = '';` and check

Comment: Tried this ... didn't work.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to do this is to use the MySQL function to get the last insert id so you can skip the second query.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO redFlag (description, severity) VALUES ('$value1', '$value2')";
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO prod_RF (cat_id, rf_id) VALUES ('$value3', LAST_INSERT_ID())";

$result1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql3); 
// the $result2 query will insert the rf_id
// so you can test this result to see if it's all successful
```

That should remove a nice chunk of PHP from your code.

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gentleman.  I've been screwing around with that issue all day and your code worked like a charm (and removed like 10+ lines of code!).  Thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `$value4` is not defined until after the `$sql3` string has been crafted. Try defining `$sql3` after you have defined `$value4`.